# XML and Latin1 issue

Tags: xml, encoding, character

Is there any simple way to just save a xml file so that it would show the latin characters?
For some strange reason I have my original file from some years back which works fine but if I copy new information into it I get:

> "The document “abc.xml” cannot be saved using the Latin1 encoding. Would you like to save it using UTF-8 instead?"

If I save it using UTF-8 the latin characters are simply overrun.

My xml file starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`

Comment: Make sure you editor's charset is set to `iso-8859-1`

Comment: I've tried/checked that already but no...

Comment: So far I've tried TextEdit, TextMate and Oxygen